# Predict the next number in the array with Tensorflow Python

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, prediction

Here is the deal, I got a python script, and as an input i have 2 arrays, one has the values of a function (x_train), the other has the time of the measured values(y_train).
The script is called from java, and the parameters look like this:

a)

```
[38.0, 45.0, 42.0, 35.0, 41.0, 45.0, 69.0, 35.0, 33.0, 34.0]
[85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0]
```

b)

```
[38.0, 45.0, 42.0, 35.0, 41.0, 45.0, 69.0, 35.0, 33.0, 34.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```

c)

```
[38.0, 45.0, 42.0, 35.0, 41.0, 45.0, 69.0, 35.0, 33.0, 34.0]
[1.562571106116E12, 1.562657506116E12, 1.562743906116E12, 1.562830306116E12, 1.562916706116E12, 1.563003106116E12, 1.563089506116E12, 1.563175906116E12, 1.563262306116E12, 1.563348706116E12]
```

All this I need to make a function of grade 9 and predict the next element of the array, that is, the coefficients of the functions (a9, a8, a7, a6, a5, a4, a3, a2, a1, a0 and the loss), and then calculate the 11th number with them.

The catch is that when I use option (a) and (c), I get NAN for all the coefficients as a result of the process, but when I use option (b), I get SOME results (it's a matter of the start parameters of the function, I'll come to it later), and with those I can work.

The script does not throw any error, and I am new to this subject, and could use some help.

Here is the whole python script:

```
import tensorflow  
import sys

s1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
s2 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
s3 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

#Trainable Parameters  
startParam0 = 2 
startParam1 = 0.1
startParam2 = 0.1
startParam3 = 0.00016
startParam4 = 0.0000002
startParam5 = 0.0000000000238
startParam6 = 0.000000003202899 
startParam7 = 0.000000000000041
startParam8 = 0.000000000000001
startParam9 = 0.0000000000000001

a0 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam0], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a1 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam1], dtype=tensorflow.float32) 
a2 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam2], dtype=tensorflow.float32) 
a3 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam3], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a4 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam4], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a5 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam5], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a6 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam6], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a7 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam7], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a8 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam8], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a9 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam9], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a10 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam2], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a11 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam3], dtype=tensorflow.float32) 
a12 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam4], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a13 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam4], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a14 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam3], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a15 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam2], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a16 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam1], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a17 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam1], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a18 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam2], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
a19 = tensorflow.Variable([startParam3], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  

variableArray = [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19]

curr_a0 = 0
curr_a1 = 0
curr_a2 = 0
curr_a3 = 0
curr_a4 = 0
curr_a5 = 0
curr_a6 = 0
curr_a7 = 0
curr_a8 = 0
curr_a9 = 0
curr_a10 = 0
curr_a11 = 0
curr_a12 = 0
curr_a13 = 0
curr_a14 = 0
curr_a15 = 0
curr_a16 = 0
curr_a17 = 0
curr_a18 = 0
curr_a19 = 0
curr_loss = 0

outputArray = [curr_a0, curr_a1, curr_a2, curr_a3, curr_a4, curr_a5, curr_a6, curr_a7, curr_a8, curr_a9, curr_a10, curr_a11, curr_a12, curr_a13, curr_a14, curr_a15, curr_a16, curr_a17, curr_a18, curr_a19]

#Training Data (inputs/outputs)  
x = tensorflow.placeholder(dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
y = tensorflow.placeholder(dtype=tensorflow.float32)  

# recive parameters from java
lines = s1.split("[")[1].split("]")[0].split(",");
y_train = []
counter = 0
for l in lines:
    s = l.strip()
    y_train.append(float(l.strip()))
    counter = counter + 1

lines = s2.split("[")[1].split("]")[0].split(",");
x_train = []
counter = 0
for l in lines:
    s = l.strip()
    x_train.append(float(s))
    counter = counter +1

grade = int(s3.strip());
linear_model = tensorflow.Variable([0], dtype=tensorflow.float32)  
sessionInput = [ None for k in range( grade + 2 ) ]
sessionOutput = [ None for k in range( grade + 2 ) ]

for i in range(grade + 1):
    s = 1
    for j in range (i): 
        s = s * x 
    linear_model = linear_model + variableArray[i] * s
    sessionInput[i] = variableArray[grade - i] 
    sessionOutput[i] = outputArray[grade - i]

#Linear Regression Loss Function - sum of the squares  
squared_deltas = tensorflow.square(linear_model - y_train)  
loss = tensorflow.reduce_sum(squared_deltas) 
curr_loss = 0
sessionInput[grade+1] = loss
sessionOutput[grade+1] = curr_loss

#Gradient descent optimizer  
#optimizer = tensorflow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)  
optimizer = tensorflow.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.25)  
train = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss)  

#Creating a session 
sess = tensorflow.Session()  

writer = tensorflow.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/log/", sess.graph)  

#Initializing variables  
init = tensorflow.global_variables_initializer()  
sess.run(init)  

#Optimizing the parameters  
for i in range(10000):  
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: x_train, y: y_train})  

#Print the parameters and loss  
outputArray = sess.run(sessionInput, {x: x_train, y: y_train})  
s = ""
for i in range(0, grade + 2):
    s = s + str(outputArray[i])
    if not(i == grade + 1):
        s = s + ","

print(s)  

writer.close()  

sess.close()
```

And java code:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter stdOutput = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

System.out.println(values); //y_train
stdOutput.println(values);
stdOutput.flush();

System.out.println(dates); //x_train
stdOutput.println(dates);
stdOutput.flush();

stdOutput.println(grade); //grade=9
stdOutput.flush();

// for reading the ouput from stream
String s1 = null;

List<Double> coefList = new ArrayList<Double>();

while ((s1 = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s1);
    if (s1.indexOf("\\[") == -1) {
        Integer n = s1.split("\\[").length;
        if (n == grade + 2) { 
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < grade+1; i++){
                    coefList.add( Double.parseDouble(s1.split("\\[")[1 + i].split("\\]")[0]));
                }
            } catch(NumberFormatException E) {
                System.err.println("Received NAN instead of a number for the parameters!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, it prints the coefficients.

In option (b) the result is this:

```
[4.3143527e-06],[-1.3367743e-05],[5.2168118e-05],[0.00026263],[0.0007228],[0.00161756],[0.00351851],[0.10692083],[0.11532306],[2.0412211],17321398.0
```

and the prediction for the 11th number is:  58.70016770335398 (which seems ok)

In option (a) and (c) the result is this: [nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],[nan],nan

No errors! Please help me solve this...because I need the parameters to be in milliseconds (as in option (c))

Let me know if you need anything more. Any options can be considered, even reducing the grade of the function or something else, as long as the result stays within range of the parameters.

Thank you.